# How to create this specific map in my areas

Tags: r, google-maps, maps, color-mapping

I used following code for creating the specific map. Unfortunately i couldn't make the required map since many attempts. Therefore, i am asking to help me to create this map.  [The required map is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsVwa.png)  and [the following code gives the map is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwngL.png) . which changings are required to make required map. please, noted that i dont have error in attached code i want modification in code that give me required map.

```
library(tidyverse)
 library(raster)
    
#obtain map from GADM.org
pak <- getData('GADM', country='Pakistan', level=1)

map <- ggplot(pak) + geom_sf()

#Object for ggplot
#Need a name for joins
pak$name = pak$NAME_1
pak_ggplot <- map_data(pak)
#map_data transform name in region

#I create a random variable for color in map
zone <- data.frame(region = unique(pak$NAME_1))
zone$other_name = runif(nrow(zone),1,10)

#Join ggplot object with variable for color
pak_ggplot <- left_join(pak_ggplot, zone)

dist <- c('Astore','Bunji','Gupis','Chilas','Gilgit','Skardu')
lat <- c(35.357,35.6431,36.2274,35.4222,35.8819,35.3247)
long <- c(74.8624,74.6342,73.4421,74.0946,74.4643,75.551)

points <- cbind.data.frame(dist,lat,long)


mapa <- ggplot(data = pak_ggplot, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = other_name)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="white",high="red")  +
  labs(title = "Pakistan Map")

mapa + geom_point(data=points,aes(x=long, y=lat, group=1)) +
  geom_text(data=points, aes(x=long, y=lat,label=dist, group=1), size=2)

pak2 <- pak_ggplot %>% filter(region=='Northern Areas')

mapa2 <- ggplot(data = pak2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = 1)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="white",high="red")  +
  labs(title = "Pakistan Map")

mapa2 + geom_point(data=points,aes(x=long, y=lat, group=1)) +
  geom_text(data=points, aes(x=long, y=lat,label=dist, group=1), size=2)
```

Comment: You need to install a required package, as stated in `Error:   Package "maps" required for "map_data:. Please install and try again.`, after running `pak_ggplot <- map_data(pak)`.

Comment: Marcelo Avila sir , i have all installed packages i attached the running code, now i attached the figure produced from my code.

Comment: ah ok. it seems that your dataset `pak2` retrieved by `getData('GADM', country='Pakistan', level=1)` does not include subregional polygons. It seems that the source doesn't provide the data you are looking for (see: https://gadm.org/maps/PAK.html). You might have to find it somewhere else.

Comment: Hello Hello sir, the point you arised , actually i am unable to understand that is why i am facing this issue , i dont know how to find regional polygons. the link you attached i searched a very related thing that i want to plot . please , tell me how i add it in my code so it gives me similar results . please see ,this https://gadm.org/maps/PAK/northernareas/northernareas_3.html

Comment: sir, please find the polygons about you are asking and add it to the code. i will appreciate your this assistance .it will be a great favor infect.

Comment: Marcelo Avila ?